# How to deploy to Tomcat on Debian

Tags: java, tomcat, debian

I'm really confused about how Tomcat works on Debian vs. Ubuntu.

This is on a clean Ubuntu on DigitalOcean:

- `sudo apt-get install tomcat`
- This creates `/opt/tomcat` with all the directories
- I rename my war to `ROOT.war` and upload it under `/opt/tomcat/webapps`
- I restart tomcat and everything works just fine

Now I'm trying to do the same thing on a clean Debian on Google Cloud Platform:

- `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`
- This sprinkles tomcat directories in multiple locations:

  `/etc/tomcat7` with config files

  `/usr/share` with tomcat7, tomcat-7-admin, tomcat7-docs, tomcat7-root, etc directories

  `/var/lib/tomcat7` with webapps and other directories

How do I deploy my `ROOT.war` in this setup?

If I upload it through manager interface, it puts it under `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/`, but I don't see it from the URL.

Moreover, I even deleted `tomcat7-root` directory altogether (which has the "It works!" page), but that page still somehow shows up at the :8080 port.

So, what's the right way to deploy my application so that it's at the root of my URL? I would appreciate detailed explanation that a novice can understand :)

Comment: Tomcat is NOT OS dependent, it works same everywhere. War file always goes into /webapps folder.

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy well, i didn't say it didn't go into /webapps, it did, albeit the directory structure is different form ubuntu, but i can't access the application from the browser. does it have to do with permissions?

Comment: You doubt may be correct, please verify folder permissions